# Foreach with array in php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

How to make a foreach with this type of array please ?

Thanks.

```
Array (
  [0] => Array (
    [0] => TPK12\"
    [1] => MRP59\"
    [2] => MSM105\"
    [3] => RGS70\"
    [4] => GDN36\"
  )
)
```

I tried that but it echoes just Array():

```
foreach($match as $value) { 
  echo $value;
}
```

Comment: Use another `foreach` on `$value`.

Comment: That exact array: `foreach($match[0] as $value)`

Answer (score 0):

For a two-dimensional array you can use this:

```
foreach($match as $subArray) { 
    foreach($subArray as $value) { 
        echo $value;
    }   
}
```

Comment: It doesn't matter how you build your array, it's just how you can read the values in a two-dimensional array. Show us your array by using `print_r`

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a multidimensional array, you need to either have a foreach inside another, or specify which array you want to iterate.

```
foreach ($match[0] as $value) {
    echo $value;
}
```